# Passing class which implements an specific Interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I got the following structure:

```
abstract class Item {}

abstract class ICarriable {}
class Apple : public Item {}
class Stick : public Item, public Carriable {}
// More Items which may or may not derive from Carriable
class Pants : public Carriable {}


Stick* StickyStick = new Stick();
Pants* CoolPants = new Pants();
void Equip(ICarriable* ItemToEquip) {
    // Do things here
}
Equip(StickyStick); // Allowed.
Equip(CoolPants); // Not Allowed.
```

Now I want a function where I can pass Items which implements Carraible. So that I can pass Stick but not an Apple.

I try to avoid an if inside of that function in case the Item cant be cast to Carriable.

Comment: I just used the necessary keywords, I tried to keep my question as simple as possible.

Comment: The keywords are not sufficient to understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps you could show the actual  code you've written to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

To me it's not clear why you would want this and I think it is a design flaw. Why would an Equip function that only uses the Carriable interface functions why does it need the parameter object to also be an Item? Does the function need Item specific functions? If you want it to just satisfy the requirement of both being an Item and Carriable you could just make a third class like 'Equipable' and let that inherit from both.